# CSS margin not working right

Tags: html, css

Can someone please tell me , why i can't add margin-top/bottom or padding-top/bottom to this "a" tag.
I need to ceter "Konoha" in the Header box

```css
html{
 background-color: white 
}


body{ 
 width: 88.5%;
 height: 1200px; 
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 2px solid black;
 background-color: #161e2c;
}

.top-box{
 margin:0 auto; 
 width: 99.5%;
 height: 153px;
 background-color: #314e59;
 border:1px solid rgb(211, 41, 97);
 box-shadow: 0px 10px 7.4px 2.6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.74);

}

a{
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 23px 0 0 5px;
 padding: 5px 5px;
 max-width: 400px;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 500%;
 background-color:pink;
 border:2px solid black;
 
 
}

.right{
 margin-top:13;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 600px;
 background-color: pink;
 border:2px solid black;
 float: right;
 text-align:center;
 color:white
}

ul{
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size:35px;
 width:100%;
 padding-left:0;

}

li{
 display:inline-block;
 padding:7px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <header class = "top-box">
  <a href="#" class = "logo">Konoha</a>
  <div class = "right">
  <ul>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
   <li>Text</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
 </header>
 </body>
```

Thanks all this problem was solved , but now i have a new problem.

1. Why cant i just use `margin-top:50%` and `margin:bottom:50%` on the classes `.logo` and `.right`
   According to what i've read `margin:bottom:50%` and `margin-top:50%` should automatically center vertically both`.right` and `.logo`in their container `header` but rather they come to some random middle place of the page

2.If i use `margin-top:x%` then when i resize the window to small the LOGO shifts from being in middle of `header`to top.

Comment: Anchors are inline elements. Add the margin/padding to the header or it's class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because margin-top/bottom or padding-top/bottom only apply for ***block element***
But `<a></a>` is a ***inline element***.

You can read about [Block formatting contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting)

You can try:

HTML code

```
<body>
    <header class = "top-box">
        <div id = 'link'><a href="#">Konoha</a></div>
    </header>
</body>
```

CSS code:

```
#link{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 100px;
margin-top: 50%;
margin-bottom: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

anchor is a `inline element` if you want to use `padding-top/bottom`,
you should using add `display:block` for anchor tag

```
a{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 100px;
display:block
}
```

**[readmore](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)**

Comment: Thanks it worked just right :) but i used diplay : inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a tag as **block element**. Add this

```
display:block
```

in a tag's CSS properties.

Or put a tag inside a block element